# Lebesgue-integrability of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb [0,\infty)$ be a non-negative, twice-differentiable function. Suppose that

- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx<\infty$,
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f''(x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty$.

Does it necessarily follow that the first derivative is integrable as well:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f'(x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty$$ in Lebesgue’s sense (*i.e.*, absolutely integrability, not merely the existence of improper integrals)?

---

More generally, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb [0,\infty)$ is a non-negative function differentiable $k\in\mathbb N$ times ($k\geq 2$), and

- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx<\infty$,
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f^{(k)}(x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty$,

then is it true that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f^{(\ell)}(x)|\,\mathrm dx<\infty\quad\text{forall $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$}?$$

---

*N.B.*: continuity is *not* assumed on $f^{(k)}$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality